# 3 processes that couldn't have had init as an initial parent

Tags: 14.04, process, init

Name 3 processes that couldn't have had init as an initial parent
can any one help me on parent which doesn't have children in Ubuntu
this question refers to Linux handbook

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, use Google, answering this for you defeats the point of your education.

Comment: Definitely rings of homework and worse yet a relatively meaningless learning exercise with so much to learn in such a short semester.

Comment: It's [an exercise in the Linux Documentation Project's _Introduction to Linux_](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_04_06.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some kernel processes are started *before* init, but have a PID ≥ 2. These processes have no parent. And the children of these processes also don't have init as an ancestor.

To see them, try `pstree 0`.

Comment: can u name some of those kernel process?

Comment: @KimiyaHaqnegahdar why? Can't you run the command?

Comment: I ran the command but I couldn't find PIDs seems it doesn't show by this command.

Comment: Then start by reading up on what pstree does.